# VBA- How can I sum some numbers with same value in different column?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to sum up the total of Total TEUS, Empty Container  & Pick Up
. Before total up I need to delete the duplicate reference number first. It will group base on same Car ,Trade name,Product, service and Port If container is empty then it will sum the empty container in column H. To make it clear it will show output as below:-

raw data as below:-

| Reference Number | Container Type | Number of Containers | Number of TEUs | Container | 1st leg | Trade name | Product | service | Port | Date | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A063 | 40 | 2 | 4 | CMAU1 | KA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | XAFEX | MY | 20/02/2021 | KAZA |
| A067 | 20 | 1 | 1 |  | KA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | XAFEX | MY | 20/02/2021 | KAZA |
| A293 | 20 | 2 | 2 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | STAA | US | 21/02/2021 | ASAF |
| A295 | 20 | 4 | 4 | GLDU2 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | STAA | US | 21/02/2021 | ASAF |
| A295 | 20 | 4 | 4 | TEMU5 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | STAA | US | 21/02/2021 | ASAF |
| A067 | 40 | 1 | 2 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A752 | 40 | 1 | 2 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A338 | 40 | 4 | 8 | CMAU4 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A338 | 40 | 4 | 8 | CMAU5 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A338 | 20 | 4 | 8 | SEGU5 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A338 | 40 | 4 | 8 | TCNU1 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A530 | 40 | 1 | 2 | TCNU6 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A084 | 40 | 2 | 4 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A218 | 40 | 2 | 4 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A306 | 20 | 1 | 1 |  | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A216 | 40 | 1 | 2 | CMAU5 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |
| A9651 | 40 | 1 | 2 | CMAU4 | CGMA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22/02/2021 | SAN |

The output I would like to be as this

| Car | Trade name | Product | service | Port | Date | Total Tues | Empty Container | Pick Up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KAZA | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | XAFEX | MY | 20-Feb-21 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| ASAF | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | STAA | US | 21-Feb-21 | 6 | 2 | 4 |
| SAN | W AFRICA | PROD AFR | SANFE | TH | 22-Feb-21 | 27 | 13 | 14 |

My Code as below:-

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet 
Dim src2Range As Range
Dim dest2Range As Range


Set sht1 = Sheets("RawData")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Forecast")

sht2.Range("A1") = "Car"
sht2.Range("B1") = "Trade name"
sht2.Range("C1") = "Product"
sht2.Range("D1") = "Service"
sht2.Range("E1") = "Port"
sht2.Range("F1") = "Date"
sht2.Range("G1") = "Total Tues"
sht2.Range("H1") = "Empty Container"
sht2.Range("I1") = "Pickup"

sht1.Range("L2:L" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A2")
sht1.Range("G2:G" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("B2")
sht1.Range("H2:H" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("C2")
sht1.Range("I2:I" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("D2")
sht1.Range("J2:J" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("E2")
sht1.Range("K2:K" & lstrow).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("F2")

Set sht2 = Sheets("Forecast")
sht2.Range("A:l").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=11, Header:=xlYes

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim Data As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        LastRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Data = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 25) 'modify
    End With

For i = 2 to LastRow

''' How to calculate the total container and empty pickup if the container is empty on column E  then group by same car , trade number , product number, service , port and date

Next i
```

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate pick up?

Comment: Your results don't make sense to me. If you remove the duplicate reference numbers before adding the values, I see only 25 `TEUs` for `SAN`. And if an empty container is one with a blank in the Container column, I only count 6 empty containers.  Also, how do you determine a pick-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Power Query solution.

With your Data, you can

- Select some cell in the Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`

  - Note the table name in line 2
  - Paste the M-Code below in place of what's there
  - Edit the Table name in line 2 to match the original table name.

Notes:

- To get the same output as you show, Empty containers is computed as the sum of the `TEUS` where the `Container` column is blank.  Is this really what you want?
- I have no idea how to compute "Pickup" from your data.
- To get your results, the `remove duplicates` operation must take into account not only the **Reference** number but also the **Car** columns.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Reference Number", type text}, 
        {"Container Type", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Number of Containers", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Number of TEUs", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Container", type text}, 
        {"1st leg", type text}, 
        {"Trade name", type text}, 
        {"Product", type text}, 
        {"service", type text}, 
        {"Port", type text}, 
        {"Date", type date}, 
        {"Car", type text}}),

    //Duplicate Ref Number AND Car    
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type", {"Reference Number","Car"}),

    //Group also on "Date" Not sure what you want as all dates are the same for each of the other grouped columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Car", "Trade name", "Product", "service", "Port","Date"}, {
        {"TEUS", each List.Sum([Number of TEUs]), type nullable number}, 

        //Note that empty containers is not related to total number of containers
        {"Empty Containers", (t) => List.Sum(Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(t,each [Container] = null),"Number of TEUs")),
             type nullable number}

        //No idea how to calculate "Pickup"
        }),
    Reorder = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Car","Trade name","Product","service","Port","Date","TEUS","Empty Containers"})
in
    Reorder
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This macro outputs your desired table less the **pick up** category (you didn't explain how to calculate it) to another sheet. There are two sub's in this macro, config both in the **CONFIG HERE** area before you try it.

```
'don't delete this
Dim r As Long

Sub main()

'CONFIG HERE
'--------------------
Dim row_start As Long: row_start = 2 'set row number where data starts
Dim main_ws As Worksheet: Set main_ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set main data sheet
Dim ts As Worksheet: Set ts = Sheets("Sheet2") 'set target sheet name
Dim car_col As String: car_col = "L"
Dim trade_name_col As String: trade_name_col = "G"
Dim product_col As String: product_col = "H"
Dim service_col As String: service_col = "I"
Dim port_col As String: port_col = "J"
Dim date_col As String: date_col = "K"
Dim tues_col As String: tues_col = "D"
Dim container_col As String: container_col = "E"
'----------------------

Call delete_duplicates

Dim memory As Long

With main_ws

    Dim last_row As Long: last_row = main_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    'start pasting in next empty row
    Dim next_row As Long: next_row = ts.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim r2 As Long: r2 = next_row - 1
    Dim r3 As Long: r3 = next_row
        
        For r = row_start To last_row
        
            Dim current_car As String: current_car = .Range(car_col & r)
            Dim next_car As String: next_car = .Range(car_col & r + 1)
    
            If .Range(container_col & r) = "" Then
                ts.Range("H" & r3) = ts.Range("H" & r3) + .Range(tues_col & r)
            End If
        
            If next_car <> current_car Then
                r3 = r3 + 1
            End If
        
            If memory = 0 Then
            
                r2 = r2 + 1
            
                ts.Range("A" & r2) = .Range(car_col & r)
                ts.Range("B" & r2) = .Range(trade_name_col & r)
                ts.Range("C" & r2) = .Range(product_col & r)
                ts.Range("D" & r2) = .Range(service_col & r)
                ts.Range("E" & r2) = .Range(port_col & r)
                ts.Range("F" & r2) = .Range(date_col & r)
                ts.Range("G" & r2) = .Range(tues_col & r)
                
                memory = 1
                
                Else
                    ts.Range("G" & r2) = ts.Range("G" & r2) + main_ws.Range(tues_col & r)
                
                    If ts.Range("A" & r2) <> main_ws.Range(car_col & r + 1) Then
                        memory = 0
                    End If
              
            End If
        
        Next
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub delete_duplicates()

'CONFIG HERE
Dim main_ws As Worksheet: Set main_ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set main data sheet
'------------------

With main_ws

Dim memory As String: memory = .Cells(2, 1)
Dim reference_number As String
Dim last_row As String: last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 3 To last_row

    reference_number = .Range("A" & r)
    If reference_number = memory Then
    .Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    
    r = r - 1
    
    Else
        memory = .Range("A" & r)
    End If

    If .Cells(r, 1) = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: this macro doesn't write the category names in the header of the new table (Car, Trade Name, Product, ...), so you should write them before running the macro.